# Different types of Function in Object_ID

Tags: sql-server, function, objectid

When creating functions, I tend to preface the creation with an existence check

```
IF Object_ID(N'myfunc', N'IF') IS NOT NULL 
DROP FUNCTION myfunc

GO
CREATE FUNCTION myfunc...
```

There are several types of [object_id](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx) to be checked for functions :

```
FN = SQL scalar function
IF = SQL inline table-valued function
TF = SQL table-valued-function
FT = Assembly (CLR) table-valued function
```

I have some questions :

1. What is the difference between **'IF'**, **'TF'** and **'FT'**  type ?
2. It is very error-prone to use

   ```
   IF Object_ID(N'myFunc', 'IF') IS NOT NULL
   ```

   as sometime the function is scalar, other cases it is table-valued etc. so I may miss the correct type check.

I see people recommending

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'myfunc') AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT'))
```

Will it suffice for checking all type of functions ? What is your recommendation ?

Comment: IF acts like macro and it is efficient, multiline TF is slower, you should use IF when possible

Comment: What's wrong with information schema tables ? (see "routine")

Comment: @lad2025 : When I create CREATE FUNCTION 'func' RETURNS TABLE RETURN(..) is it a IF or a TF?

Comment: @DavidBrabant : Can you elaborate ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188757.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 1) IF vs multiline TF vs CLR TF

**Inline Table Valued Function**

Acts like macro, very efficient can be treated like parametrized view

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.name(@param INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN 
   SELECT ...
   FROM tab t
   WHERE t.Col = @param;
GO
```

**Multi Statement Table Valued Function**

More flexible you can do many intermediate steps if needed but it will be slower than IF.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.name()
RETURNS @Result TABLE
(Col_name    INT         NOT NULL,
...
)
AS
BEGIN
    /* Many operations */

    INSERT @Result
    SELECT *
    FROM ...

    RETURN
END
GO
```

**CLR Table-Valued Functions**

[From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131103.aspx)

> **Transact-SQL table-valued functions materialize the results of calling
>   the function into an intermediate table. Since they use an
>   intermediate table, they can support constraints and unique indexes
>   over the results. These features can be extremely useful when large
>   results are returned.**
>
> **In contrast, CLR table-valued functions represent a streaming
>   alternative.** There is no requirement that the entire set of results be
>   materialized in a single table. The IEnumerable object returned by the
>   managed function is directly called by the execution plan of the query
>   that calls the table-valued function, and the results are consumed in
>   an incremental manner. This streaming model ensures that results can
>   be consumed immediately after the first row is available, instead of
>   waiting for the entire table to be populated. It is also a better
>   alternative if you have very large numbers of rows returned, because
>   they do not have to be materialized in memory as a whole. For example,
>   a managed table-valued function could be used to parse a text file and
>   return each line as a row.

## 2) Checking if function exists:

Check [ROUTINES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188757.aspx) catalog:

> Returns one row for each stored procedure and function that can be
>   accessed by the current user in the current database.

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT  1
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
            WHERE Specific_schema = 'dbo'
              AND specific_name = 'Foo'
              AND Routine_Type = 'FUNCTION' )
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the schema name and remove the object type. Why do you need to check if the object is a function? Think this through:

```
if object_id(N'dbo.functionname') is not null
drop function dbo.functionname
go
create function dbo.functionname ...
```

... will drop the function if it exists, then create it.

If there is already an object named "dbo.functionname" and it is NOT a function, the drop will fail. But that's true whether or not you check that "dbo.functionname" is a function or not.

In other words, if there is a TABLE (or any other non-function object) named `dbo.functionname`, then

```
if object_id(N'dbo.functionname', N'IF') -- equates to false
drop function dbo.functionanme -- doesn't get run
go
create function dbo.functionname... -- generates error
```

would fail on the `create` function (because the table dbo.functionname would not be dropped).

You can't have two objects with the same schema.objectname. So if you just check for `object_id(N'schema.objectname')`, you should be fine.